# How do you organize folders for future scaling?

Tags: online-storage

What is the best way to organize folders for future scaling? I'm in progress to launch a new website. I expect that in the future I will have to deal with storage capacity of uploaded photos, respectively I will have to distribute them on multiple hard drivers.
Currently I use something like this:

/1/1/photo.jpg
/1/2/photo.jpg
.
/10/10/photo.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I use part of a file hash as a file name (and store the hash in the database), then organize them into subdirectories based on the first letter (or letters). For example, file `de9f2c7fd25e1b3afad3e85a.jpg` goes to

```
/storage/d/de9f2c7fd25e1b3afad3e85a.jpg
```

Since hashes are evenly distributed it's easy to split the store to multiple drives, every directory should have about the same number of images. Currently, I have about 2TB worth of images organized like this, and it works like a charm.

Btw, one neat thing about this is if you somehow mess up your filenames, you won't have gazillion of images unorganized, just hash them and you're back to business.

Comment: i use something like /storage/de/9f/de9f2c7fd25e1b3afad3e85a.jpg -- figure that a 2-level, 256-branching tree (65536 dirs max) will keep the # of files per dir at a reasonable level.

Answer (score 0):

Unique timestamped URLs would be a good start, f.e.
2009/11/30/photo-widthxheight-{other extracted EXIF information}.jpg